# Rings with the property $\dim R-\dim R/p\leq \text{const}$ for all minimal $p$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

I'm curious if there exists a class of rings generalizing quasi-unmixed rings. I guess a generalization of quasi-unmixed rings can be done as follows:
For a fixed integer $i$
$$\forall p\in\operatorname{Min} R,\quad \dim R- \dim R/p\leq i$$ 
($i=0$ gives the quasi-unmixed rings.)

**Have such rings been studied and characterized?**